# Epsilon proof for a sequence that converges to 1/2.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that this sequence $$\frac{n+2}{2n+3} $$ converges to $1/2$. This is what I have so, far.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N=\dfrac{1}{4\epsilon}$ and let $n > N$ where $n$ is  some integer. 
Then $n>\dfrac{1}{4\epsilon}> \dfrac{1}{4\epsilon} -\dfrac{3}{2}$.

So, $4n >\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}-6$ and $4n+6 >\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$. Thus, $\dfrac{1}{4n+6} < \epsilon$  and hence

$$\left|\frac{n+2}{2n+3}-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \left|\frac{2(n+2)}{2(2n+3)} -\frac{(2n+3)}{2(2n+3)} \right| = \left|\frac{1}{4n+6}\right|=\frac{1}{4n+6} < \epsilon $$

Is there any flaw in my proof?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me! Perhaps it would have been nicer if the last steps were $$\mid -\frac{1}{4n+6}\mid=\frac{1}{4n+6}<\epsilon$$ but that's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @EBP : It really is $+1$, not $-1$, in the numerator: $2(2) - 3 = 1$, right?

Comment: This is a valid proof, and is as fundamental as it gets. Personally, I would simply write that the sequence is equal to ${1\over2}+{1\over4n+6}$ which by property of limits converges to ${1\over2}+0$, as the second term is smaller than ${1\over n}$ which generally can be assumed to converge to $0$

Comment: @stanley I think they wanted him to "hook" it back to the epsilon-delta definition, so can't use the additive property.

Comment: @MPW this is awkward, you are totally right!

Comment: @EBP : I have to disclose that I did the same thing when I first looked at this question. I think I mentally did $2-3=-1$. So, no shame there.